# How to return link to an external URL in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a web application with form. When I click to save, application creates some file and returns some url. How I can display this url to web page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ExternalLink`.

A normal static link:

```
new ExternalLink("link", "http://some.url", "This is a some.url link");
```

Depending on the context may be better to use this other constructor that admits and `IModel` of your `href` and `label` parameters:

```
ExternalLink(final String id, final IModel<String> href, final IModel<?> label)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to simply create a Link and override the onComponentTag method:

The html part:

```
...
<a wicket:id="link">[link]</a>
...
```

The java part:

```
...
Link link = new Link("link") {
    @Override
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
        tag.put("href", "http://www.example.com/");
    }
};
add(link);
...
```