# Open an external link in a wicket modal window

Tags: wicket

I'm pretty new to wicket, so apologies if this is very easy - I'd like to open an external link in a modal window. The url is fixed and isn't a lot more than a static page - how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the modal window to display the contents of the external link?

Comment: Yes, exactly - sorry, I can see how that would be confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money would be on the `Include` component. [Javadoc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/include/Include.html). [Example in wicket examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.IncludePage)

I'm afraid I didn't ever have to use this particular component, so I can't provide any more information, but it looks like you should be able to use it like any other wicket component with no particular complications.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at ExternalLink. You can use it like so:

java:

```
ExternalLink link = new ExternalLink("linkid", "http://www.google.com");
add(link);
```

with html

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="linkid">Link</a>
```

btw. Google is your friend when developing wicket. Lots of questions have already been asked, inlcuding [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210908/how-to-return-link-to-an-external-url-in-wicket).

Comment: ok cool - so I should create a new modal window and add the external link in there?